# Saving Pictures with Data

Tags: ios, image, save

I know how to save a picture and this is the code until now. This code shows that the user taps a button and is able to take a photo.

```
-(IBAction)TakePhoto {
picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker.delegate = self;
[picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (IBAction)ChooseExisting {
picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
picker2.delegate = self;
[picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
[self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:nil];

}


- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[imageview setImage:image];

//Save Your Image ======
UIImage *yourImage  = imageview.image;//imageView.image;
NSString *docDirPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
NSString *filePath = [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myImageFile.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(yourImage) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}


- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

However I want to sort my saved pictures into 6 Category or Genres which the user has to tap using the segment view control.    Is this possible to do?  I am very new in ios programming and objective-c in xcode and confused with many view controllers however I really like this to work and I a cannot find any resource about this topic. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want user to select a category to save to?

Comment: Yes! user takes picture within app and it saves so that the user can see the picture in the app and not in the photo library..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good demo for saving images to particular album using ALAssetsLibrary:

http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/

I hope it will help you out...

or

You can create different libraries using this piece of code:

```
-(void)createDirectory:(NSString *)directoryName atFilePath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    NSString *filePathAndDirectory = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:directoryName];
    NSError *error;

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePathAndDirectory
                                   withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                                    attributes:nil
                                                         error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Create directory error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

And fetch the images through their respective paths!!!

For more information see this: http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/08/ios-application-directory-structure.html

Comment: Sorry I want don't want it to save into a photo album, I want the user to input the data and then save it inside the app. and Thanks for the site too.

Comment: What you mean by inside the app?? Where are you going to store those images in a local database? or a web server?

Comment: so its an app that a user takes a photo in side the app then he sorts the photo in a category to save (meaning he can access the photo just in the app). SAVING IN THE APP..

Comment: I have edited the answer...check if its gonna help you or not!!

Comment: Thanks ill try! u just have to change the directoryName to something u likerite?